# Task frezees UI when starts after showing a dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, responsive-design, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

Suppose we want to show a dialog, when getting an exception in the `task1` and from that dialog we call a method, which starts a new `task2`. The problem is that the owner window freezes during `task2`.

Please, take a look at the simple code ([Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) uses):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew
      (() => SomeHardMethod(1)).ContinueWith(TaskContinuation, scheduler);
}
private void TaskContinuation(Task parentTask)
{   
    if (parentTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // If we get an exception - show a dialog that starts a new task
        var dlg = new WindowDialog();  
        var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        if (dlg.Show())
        {   
          //Here we start a new task
           Task.Factory.StartNew
             (() => SomeHardMethod(2)).ContinueWith(TaskContinuation, scheduler);
        }
        var ex = parentTask.Exception;
    }
}
private void SomeHardMethod(int mode)
{   
    if (mode == 1)
    {    
         throw new ArgumentException("mode");
    }
    else
    {   //Any long operation...
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }    
}
```

To me, its strange that, when I firstly start the task in `button1_Click` method it performs not in UI, but when I secondly start a new task it performs in UI thread, so that's why the owner window freezes.

Could anyone clarify why does this part of code actually start the task not in background?

```
if (dlg.Show())
{
    //Here we start a new task
    Task.Factory.StartNew
      (() => SomeHardMethod(2)).ContinueWith(TaskContinuation, scheduler);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `WindowDialog` and what does its `Show()` do?

Comment: It actually doesn't metter. In my case it just shows a window, and there is one button, that just close it (DialogResult = true)

Comment: It should ShowDialog() the window. Details matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a `Task` using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, the [current scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current.aspx) is used. What this means is that if you start a `Task` this way from a `Task` that executes on the UI thread, it will execute on the UI thread too. But the same won't happen if you start a `Task` from the UI thread, but outside of a `Task` (like in your event handler).

To make sure the `Task` is executed on a background thread, you need to explicitly specify you want to use [`TaskScheduler.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for clarification! This helps to understand the mechanism now I will try to solve the problem, using your hint.